# Unable to remove two consecutive characters using M code

Tags: excel, syntax-error, powerquery

[Regarding Excel Power Query M Syntax]

Start with the simple formula

```
= Text.Remove("abcdefxyz", "yz")
```

The logical value generated from this formula should be `abcdefx`
But when I execute the formula, it just generates the following error

```
Expression.Error: The value isn't a single-character string.
Details:
   Value = yz
```

Why?
And how do I need to alter the code so that it generates the logical value of `abcdefx`?

(I will also point out that if I change this formula to read

```
= Text.Remove("abcdefxyz", "z")
```

It does produce the logical value of `abcdefxy`
and does not produce an error.)

Comment: `Text.Remove()` takes single chars. Either a single one or in list form. Look into `Text.Replace()` instead.